# How to use the same selenium session with different test cases?

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-rc

I'm using JUnit and Selenium. I would like to log in once to a web page, after run I run two test cases, without opening a new browser/session. If I do the "logging in" in `setUp()` method, then this called at every time before the test cases. How can I use only one `setUp()` method for all of my test cases?

Comment: do you need to change users between tests?

Comment: No, the same user is good for me.

Comment: @Balint You can make better usage of the '@AfterClass' & '@BeforeClass' annotations

Comment: @QATest I tried to put my setUp() method in '@BeforeClass', and it opened a new browser for the second test case. Or do you think another thing?

Comment: @Balint I am able to work fine with what I said. I would like to see your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be achieved in the following manner

```
package com.java;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class TestAnnt {

    public static Selenium sel;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 5555, "*firefox",
                "http://www.google.com");
        sel.start();
        System.out.println("Before Class");
    }

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {

        System.out.println("Before Test");

        // Actions before a test case is executed
    }

    @Test
    public void testone() {
        sel.open("/");
        sel.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        System.out.println("Test one");
        // Actions of test case 1
    }

    @Test
    public void testtwo() {
        sel.open("http://au.yahoo.com");
        sel.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        System.out.println("test two");
        // Actions of test case 2
    }

    @After
    public void afterTest() {
        System.out.println("after test");
        // Actions after a test case is executed
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        sel.close();
        sel.stop();
        sel.shutDownSeleniumServer();
        System.out.println("After Class");
    }

}
```

Comment: @Balint, I am updating my answer and you can verify it

Comment: Thank you, you helped a lot to me. Now I understand these annotations.