# Selenium WebDriver-How can i run suite of testcases in single browser window?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

My question is -Is it possible to run a suite of testcases in single instance of browser ie only need to login to application once and also this window should not get close even if any of the testcase in the suite gets fail.If yes then how can i implement .Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you have something like `@AfterClass public static void end(){driver.close();}` for each testcase class. 
Can you show an example ? And tell us what language you are using.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932632/how-to-use-the-same-selenium-session-with-different-test-cases

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing - What you are trying to achieve is - scenario/flow testing (in my words) and selenium  / JUnit testcases are not suitable for this.

The way we achieve it in our project is to design the flow / Scenario tests as java classes ( not test cases ) and then run them through a JUnit TestCase. This way you create a Single instance of the browser in your test method and run detailed scenarios on it.

Any test asserts that fail needs to be manually designed and you will need to rely on custom exceptions to be thrown to fail the test.

The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932632/how-to-use-the-same-selenium-session-with-different-test-cases) pointed to by Tim has a problem that you need to assume the sequence / order of tests which is not guaranteed and may cause your tests to fail.